# Select a type of sender for email with wildcard

Tags: applescript

I would like to send an email with applescript. This script will be used on a few computers and the email should be sent by a certain type of account containing "mynetwork.com" in the email address.

Is there a way to automatically select the computer email account containing "my network.com" ? Obviously the wildcard * is not working see code below

```
 property faxboxEmail : {"fax@opilbox.com"}
 property theNumber : ""
 property theContent : ""
 property theSender : "*@mynetwork.com"

tell application "Mail"
  set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true,      subject:theNumber, content:theContent, sender:theSender}
       tell newMessage
  make new to recipient with properties {address:faxboxEmail}
       end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender address for accounts in Mac OS X Mail are stored in the `sender addresses` property in an `account`. So, technically what you want is something like `get account whose email addresses ends with "@mynetwork.com"`. However, the `email addresses` property is a simple list, and AppleScript doesn’t have dynamic searches into lists like that.

However, the number of accounts on any personal computer should be fairly small, so looping through them shouldn’t be a problem.

```
property faxboxEmail : {"fax@opilbox.com"}
property theNumber : "Nine"
property theContent : "Hello, World"

set foundAddress to false

tell application "Mail"
    repeat with potentialSender in accounts
        tell potentialSender
            repeat with potentialAddress in email addresses as list
                if potentialAddress ends with "@mynetwork.com" then
                    set foundAddress to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
        if foundAddress then
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    if foundAddress then
        set senderName to full name of potentialSender
        set senderAddress to senderName & " <" & potentialAddress & ">"
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:theNumber, content:theContent, sender:senderAddress}
        tell newMessage
            make new to recipient with properties {address:faxboxEmail}
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

You may also find it useful to look at the properties of each account, using something like:

```
tell application "Mail"
    --or “account 1”, “account 3”, etc., up to the number of accounts
    get properties of account 2
end tell
```

If you run that and then look in the *results* pane, you’ll see all of the properties, including the `email addresses` property. If your script isn’t doing what you expect it to do, post not just the script, but also the values of the property you’re looking at, in this case the `email addresses` property. You will probably want to use a test computer with fake example.com, example.org, and example.net email addresses, so as not to expose real email addresses to harvesters.

You also may find it easier to build your scripts from the ground up. For example, in this case, you would want to write a script that sends a hard-coded email from a hard-coded sender. Only once that aspect of the script is working, would you want to add the wrinkle about searching for a dynamic sender. This will simplify your programming process by making each task smaller, and will also make it more obvious where the code is going astray.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seems to work. If I use "ends with ".com" then it is ok but if I use "ends with ".me" it doesn't find any accounts and there is an error because the foundAddress was not defined. I have accounts ending with .com, .ch and .me

Comment: More preciselyI have accounts ending with emailx@blah.com, emaily@blo.ch, emailz@bla.me and I wish to select only the @blo.ch accounts

Comment: I’ve modified the example to include an initialization of the foundAddress variable, so that when there is no matching address the if/then doesn’t fail. I also added some advice on examining the values of each account.

Comment: Actually, by looking into the values of the property, I found out that your script is working very well but it is the command "set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:theNumber, sender:senderAddress, content:theContent}" that is not working properly and not taking into account the senderAddress properly. Any idea why ?

Comment: Ah, yes. The format of the sender address is very specific. It must include the name of the sender as well as their address. I’ve modified the script to take that into account.